# Change date from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert a string from my database that is formatted as YYYYMMDD and is placed in the input box `id="startingdate"`. How would I convert it to YYYY-MM-DD at the other input box `id="startingdate1"`?

```
<input type="" id="startingdate1" name="startingdate1" size="20" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
<input id="startingdate" name="startingdate" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: I think you should use momentjs

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon—it doesn't seem sensible to load a few thousand lines of library, convert the string to a date, then convert it back to a string again in a slightly different format just to insert two hyphens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using a regular expression if for some reason you don't want to:

```js
var startDate = document.getElementById('startingdate').value;
var displayDate = document.getElementById('startingdate1');

var year = startDate.substring(0, 4);
var month = startDate.substring(4, 6);
var day = startDate.substring(6, 8);

displayDate.value = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
```

```html
<input type="" id="startingdate1" name="startingdate1" size="20" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
<input id="startingdate" name="startingdate" type="hidden" value="20160415"/>
```

Comment: Or even `[s.slice(0, 4), s.slice(4,6), s.slice(6,8)].join('-')`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG That's actually the best solution to this question, but regex is pretty awesome too.

Comment: as a very new programmer, your answer helped me in understanding the logic to handle this problem the most. So, thank you!

Answer (score 18):

```
s = s.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
```

This uses a regular expression to replace a sequence of four digits, followed by a sequence of two digits, followed by a sequence of two digits, with the first, plus a `-`, plus the second, plus a `-`, plus the third.

Comment: I just love when I'm trying to solve a problem concerning string manipulation, and then I remember -- *"Oh yeah, there's a whole language dedicated to parsing strings"*

Comment: @4castle Thank you so much actually i m beginner i m trying to improve my skills thanks for suggestion

Comment: This didn't work in my js browser console, nor my node console. any reason why?

Comment: s = "YYYYMMDD";
s = s.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
console.log(s);

Comment: s = '20160416'; // here use digits insteads of words
s = s.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3'); // if you want words the replace the d with w
console.log(s);

Comment: like this s = 'YYYYMMDD';
s = s.replace(/(\w{4})(\w{2})(\w{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3'); 
console.log(s);

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way for me so far was:

```
var a = "YYYYMMDD";
var b = [a.slice(0, 4), "-", a.slice(4, 6), "-", a.slice(6, 8)].join('');
console.log(b);
```

Comment: If you remove the `-` from inside the array, you can just put `.join('-')`

Answer (score 3):

Cleaner, simpler version:

```js
function dateFormat(value, pattern) {
  var i = 0,
    date = value.toString();
  return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => date[i++]);
}
var displayDate = dateFormat('19700101', '####-##-##');
console.log(displayDate);
```